# Compare a data from three Arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

I need to make some kind of calculator, and I want to do this while using three different arrays...

```
var = Month; 
var = Num_of_Month;
var = Days_of_Month;
var = Year;

  Month = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
  Num_of_Month = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
  Days_of_Month = new Array(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31); 
  Year = new Array(2014, 2015, 2016);
```

How do I compare them?

Comment: The syntax of the code you have posted is invalid in JavaScript.

Comment: What do you mean by compare? Maybe you should add some examples.

Comment: In this example, i must find, what date user are chosen, and to tell him a total number of days that he chosen

Comment: start with valid JS: month = [...], or month = new Array(...)

Comment: where and how does the user input his data?

Comment: i give to user, two dates ( in .datepicker ) , and give him a selection of places, that he need to choose. With submit button, i need to calculate all of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is get the dates the user selects and calculate the number of days between them, and if you are truly using datepicker then you can do this without using 3 arrays.

Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tihg7947/36m61jnj/2/) to get an idea.

```
$("#StartDate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
});
$("#EndDate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,        
    onSelect: function () {
        datediff();
    }
});

function datediff() {
    if (($('#StartDate').val().length !== 0) && ($('#EndDate').val().length !== 0)) {

        var StartDate = $('#StartDate').datepicker('getDate');
        var EndDate = $('#EndDate').datepicker('getDate');
        //Divide by 1000ms, 60secs, 60mins, 24hours - you get number of days.
        var numOfDays = Math.abs(new Date(EndDate - StartDate))/1000/60/60/24;
        alert(numOfDays + ' Days');
    }
}
```